# Google analytics api V4- I can't see historical data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Google analytics api V4- I can't see historical data
Which may be the reason that I can only see data through the API from a certain date.
From GA, I can see everything without a problem.

What can be the reason that the data is only available from 2018?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the reason, data settings in GA - Administration -> Service -> Data storage.
I will see after 24h whether they will be visible.